# Outlines display option "visible layers" does not work. How to fix it?

Tags: interface, outliner, optimization, visibility

When i select display mode of "Visible laters" only in outliner, it still shows objects that are on other layers, that are currently not visible. Even when current layer is empty.

How to fix that?

Comment: Do you mean Visible Layers dropdown in the Outliner? What Blender version do you use? Could you provide some screenshots of the objects on the other scene layers visible while desired layer is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 3D view that you want the outliner to update on depending on what layer you're on, click the square with a link in front of it.
[image]